# Solar inverter/charger to battery connection protection

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a solar off grid inverter/MPPT charger and I want to install protection on the link between the unit and the battery.

I thought of using a Circuit Breaker like [this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B07QTQ4XQQ/?coliid=IGUAYD8665U11&colid=10K7RHH7409EM&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it). But the problem is that DC circuit breaker is directional as I understand, because you have a side that you should link to load and side to the battery. And in the case of this unit the same link to the battery can draw DC current or send it.

The question is: can I use two on serial on the same positive link each in different direction so I cover both ways? Thanks!

Comment: A fuse is bidirectional.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I have read that it only protects you from over-current but not from other DC hazards, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your charger probably has short circuit protection/current limiting built in.   Otherwise or if you want a lower current limit why not use a simple fuse. Do you expect it to blow often?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

DC circuit breakers are not typically directional.
They are different that AC circuit breakers, and typically more expensive, but not directional.

An AC circuit breaker can depend on the fact that an AC current goes through zero twice on every cycle, where it is reversing direction.

A DC circuit breaker can not depend on the current going through zero. It has to break the arc while there is still full current. This is more difficult.

There are thyristor-based DC switches, which are directional, but they aren't circuit breakers, and are not used for safety disconnects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So what do you suggest to use to protect the unit in case it is charging or drawing for the inverter.